# bootstrap datetimepicker format issue

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using Datetime picker for below input tag:
`<input asp-for="Ticket_Date" id="ticketDate" type="datetime" style="width: 160px; margin-left: -45px; flex-wrap:nowrap; background-color: lemonchiffon;" class="datepicker form-control" />`

Here is my Jquery to select Datetime:

```
        $("#ticketDate").datepicker({
            dropdownParent: $('#call_log'),
            format: "dd-mm-yyyyThh:mm:ss",
            autoHide: true
        }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
            $(this).datepicker('hide');           
        });
```

It works well for the format "dd-mm-yyyy". For date with time When change for like  "dd-MM-yyyyThh:mm:ss" it does not work and give us wrong result e.g, "13-06-2023Thh:06:ss".

I am using below libraries :-

```
<link href="~/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/lib/select2/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/twitter-bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/select2/js/select2.js"></script>
```

lots of articles from Stackoverflow.